# check_mk send notifications based on service status in Nagios

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I have some services status in "Warning", "Unknown" and "Critical". I would like to send notifications for "Warnings" and "Unknown" every hour and for "Critical" every 10 minutes. Right now my set up only sends notifications for "Critical" every 30 minutes. I have not seen how to change it based on status:

```
extra_service_conf["notification_interval"] = [
 ( "30",  ALL_HOSTS, ALL_SERVICES )
]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Log in via WATO as an administrative user
- Find the "Host & Service
  Parameters"
- Find "Monitoring Configuration"
- Find "Periodic
  notifications during service problems"

From this point, I think you'll be able to handle it.

Comment: Hi. I'm not using WATO

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the answer
https://forum.checkmk.com/t/check-mk-english-activate-periodic-notification-only-for-critical-state/12747

```
WATO - Configuration -> Host and Service Parameters ->

Monitoring Configuration -> Periodic notifications during host
problems
```

I think it defaults to every 60 minutes. I created a rule in the

main folder to set it to 1440 (once a day).